# The correct way to change object __proto__ property

Tags: javascript

I know javascript prototype inheritance pretty well but I have a situation similar to angular `scopes` and I don't know how to handle it.

Let's begin with **wrong** (because it is bad idea to change `__proto__` property) but **working** example

https://jsfiddle.net/hxm61r7j/

```
function Scope() {
}

Scope.prototype.$new = function() {
    var new_scope = new Scope();

    //TODO: change line bellow 
    new_scope.__proto__ = this;

    return new_scope;
}

// Create root scope
var scope_level_1 = new Scope();
scope_level_1.a = 'scope_level_1 a';
scope_level_1.b = 'scope_level_1 b';

// Create scope which inherits from parent
var scope_level_2 = scope_level_1.$new();
scope_level_2.b = 'scope_level_2 b';

// We don't have property "a" in "scope_level_2" so it will be taken from "scope_level_1"
// But we have property "b" in "scope_level_2" so it will be taken from there
console.log(scope_level_2.a, scope_level_2.b);
```

As you see I need a way to create some kind of `scope` which will have some properties. Later I need to create other `scope` which will inherit from previous one. I mean if property is not defined in current scope it will be taken from parent one.

But I'm not sure how to change this line: `new_scope.__proto__ = this;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: @RobertRossmann It is not this case. I know how to use `prototype` in usual cases. For example if I need to have constructor `Vehicle` and two other constructors `Car` and `Motorbike` and they both inherits from `Vehicle`. But in this case I need only one constructor `Scope` which inherits from itself

Comment: Inheriting from itself will not help achieve anything - any property which exists on `Scope` would be immediately resolved on current object and everything else will be unresolvable (i.e. `undefined`) at best; at worst, the engine will reach maximum stack trace while trying to recursively find your property. What is your use case for such behaviour...?

Comment: I think I got it... Posting answer shortly.

Comment: I hope you got it @RobertRossmann :) Note that example is working and I think it describes what is my case. I just don't like that I change `__proto__` property directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

This function allows you to create a new JavaScript object with the internal prototype property (`__proto__`) set to whatever object you pass to the function as first argument:

```
Scope.prototype.$new = function() {
    var new_scope = Object.create(this);
    // If you also need to call the constructor function:
    Scope.call(new_scope);

    return new_scope;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), but this is part of ECMAScript 6 and browser support may vary:

```
Scope.prototype.$new = function() {
    var new_scope = new Scope();

    Object.setPrototypeOf(new_scope, this);

    return new_scope;
}
```

Note that the `__proto__` property has only been standardised in ES 6 and its direct manipulation is therefore discouraged.

Comment: what if I want to modify the `__proto__` of an `Array`? This only works on `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

First of it is not a good practice to use dunder proto , there is setPrototyOf for that cause

[setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Unless of course you need to support the older IE versions.

Now remember that after setting teh prototype you ALSO need to set the constructor again.
So the correct would be 
new_scope.**proto** = this.prototype;
new_scope.**proto**.constructor=this.prototype.constructor

Comment: a good explanation  available in http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033738.do

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (@Robert first posted so I accepted his answer). And many thanks for a book. I love reading books!

Comment: But why is it bad practice to use this? I think `angularjs` does it in similar way, and I love that I can access variables from parent scope. My case is exactly the same

Comment: Bad practice is **changing** prototypes of **existing objects**; there's nothing wrong with creating objects with custom prototypes. It can break optimisations.